# How to persist a component across all screens in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, chatbot

I'm trying to persist the chat-bot component across all screens in my Angular project. I tried to refer the component's selector in app.component.html like the below code

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<section>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
<app-chat-popup></app-chat-popup>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

But it is not linking the component as expected. If I refer as a normal component that gets triggered on a button click then it is working as expected. But I need it to be in all the screens in my project. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:
This is my Chat component HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Message box -->
    <div class="chat_box">
      <div class="chat_header">
        <!-- <img src="user.jpg" class="user_icon" /> -->
        <h4 class="username">Virtual agent</h4>
        <i class="fas fa-times close"></i>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div *ngIf="chatVisible" class="message_content">
          <ng-container #messageList *ngFor="let message of messages | async">

              <div class="message" [ngClass]="{ 'from': message.sentBy === 'bot',
                                                'to':   message.sentBy === 'user' }">
                {{ message.content }}
              </div>

            </ng-container>
      </div>
      <div class="input_box">
        <input [(ngModel)]="formValue" (keyup.enter)="sendMessage()" placeholder="Your message here..." type="text">
        <button (click)="sendMessage()">se</button>
        <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say the sample code you provided isn't working as expected what do you mean ?

Comment: Is the chat component part of the root module?

Comment: @ViktorGarba, The sample code is where I'm trying to display my chat bot UI, but I don't know if I'm trying the right way as it is not displaying the chat UI as expected

Comment: @christian Chat component is a part of chatModule which in turn is a part of root Module

Comment: Define "is a part of". Post the code of both modules. Also, it doesn't male sense for a component view to be a complete HTML page.

Comment: A better approach would be lazyload the chat bot module https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093. Advantage is you can keep it as a separate application and also deploy it as independent. It's not like Angular lazy load , a little different concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar to this using @ViewChild for a modal that appears on every page of a website using ngx-bootstrap. If your chatbot window can be assigned to a modal, this should work fine. I'm using Angular 8 btw.

You just need to import your modal module into your root component as a typical component, and leave your index.html the way it is, separately referencing the modal component outside of your routing component.

```
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
export class LoginBannerComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
}

@ViewChild('autoShownModal', { static: false })
autoShownModal: ModalDirective;
isModalShown = true;

showModal(): void {
    this.isModalShown = true;
}

hideModal(): void {
    this.autoShownModal.hide();
}

onHidden(): void {
    this.isModalShown = false;
}
accept(): void {
    this.autoShownModal.hide();
}

reject(): void {
    this.isChildModalShown = true;
    this.isModalShown = false;

}
```

And my HTML template:

```
<div #autoShownModal="bs-modal"
 (onHidden)="onHidden()"
 *ngIf="isModalShown"
 [config]="{ show: true, animated: true, backdrop: true, ignoreBackdropClick: true }"
 aria-labelledby="dialog-auto-name"
 bsModal
 class="fade modal"
 role="dialog"
 tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body text-white"
             style="background-color: #0072CE">
            <p class="font-weight-bold h4 text-capitalize text-center">MODAL CONTENT HERE</p>
            <div class="modal-footer text-white">
                <button (click)="accept()"
                        class="btn btn-success mr-auto"
                        type="button">
                    Accept
                </button>
                <button (click)="reject()"
                        class="btn btn-danger"
                        type="button">
                    Reject
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use libraries like moment.js and angular local storage to only display modals based on amounts of time since page has been visited, etc.

Answer (score 0):

other way `<router-outlet><yourComponent></yourComponent></router-outlet>` works fine for chatbots